How to terminate a function which is working in python?
I want to make a code which works like this: after certain seconds I want to terminate the working function in the main function.
I've tried the below code but when the code in the loop function isn't an async function(like await asyncio.sleep(1)) it doesn't work.
import asyncio

async def loop():
    while True:
        pass


async def main():
    task = asyncio.Task(loop())
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('1223')
    task.cancel()
    print('x')

asyncio.run(main())


You can add a flag which the running function checks periodically and exits if it changes. Everything else is more or less unreliable and may make the application unstable. Second best approach is to run the function in a separate process and terminate that process.

This question is similar to: asyncio CancelledError and KeyboardInterrupt. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@SergiiKozlov Here the cancel is not invoked because while True hangs the event loop, so arguably it is a different question. cf. “IO-bound functions/methods that would otherwise block the event loop if they were run in the main thread”

Is your ultimate requirement to (somehow) stop an async function? Are subprocesses or threads an option?

Use multiprocessing. When you want a function to be terminated after certain seconds, then all the function should start running simultaneously. My comments inside the code explains the rest.
import multiprocessing as mp
import time as t

# function which needs to be terminated after certain seconds
def func1():
  # Do something
  
def func2():
  # Do something

# A function to terminate func1      
def stop(func):

    # terminate the func after 1 sec
    t.sleep(1)
    
    func.terminate()


# Add execution guard in case "spawn"-multiprocessing mode is used
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Create two processes
    pro_1 = mp.Process(target=func1)
    pro_2 = mp.Process(target=func2)
    
    # third process being stop() and the args being pro_1
    pro_3 = mp.Process(target=stop, args=(pro_1,))
    
    # Start the processes
    pro_1.start()
    pro_2.start()
    pro_3.start()
    
    
    
    #As the pro_1 is terminated use process.join for only pro_2 and pro_3
    pro_2.join()
    pro_3.join()


The shown code only works if process creation happens in fork mode (by default Linux only) but not in spawn mode.

@MichaelButscher, Thanks, I edited after seeing your comment. If I'm right I remember as if I had commented the same already here. Don't know why .. I find that the comment has disappeared.

Unfortunately that's not the way to handle this correctly (actually nearly the opposite). I have edited your code to show how it should be done.

@MichaelButscher, Thank you for your correction. As I'm using linux, I didn't get a chance to use it.  My only doubt is, How will  it take spawn mode just by mentioning if __name__ == '__main__'? Don't we need to mention anywhere that mp.set_start_method('spawn')?

It's the other way around: If spawn mode is used (the only option on Windows and default on Mac OS) this guard is necessary. With fork no special measures are necessary at all but the guard doesn't hurt.

@MichaelButscher  I understand now that the guard  if __name__ == 'main':, guard is necessary. But what I assume is: after the line if __name__ == 'main':, there should be a next line mp.set_start_method('spawn').  I think you omitted it due to oversight.

Official Document :  https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method

There is no reason to set the start method, the code works with all start methods.
